# How to handle dialog through unit tests?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, c#-3.0

i am writing unit test for a C# project.
One of the event handler raises a kind of Save as dialog wherein I have to enter a path and file name. On it's ok click, I want to receive this string. How can I handle this.

thanks,
kapil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want the UI to actually appear during a unit test.  At that point, it's no longer a unit test.  If you really want to test the UI, unit testing is not the place for it, instead use a [UI testing framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUI_software_testing).  If you want to test some functionality underlying the UI, you will need to redesign your program so that whatever code is executing as a result of UI actions is independently testable.

Comment: +1. I Totally agree. Once a developer has to click away popup boxes while running unit tests, he will stop running unit tests often, because it takes too much time. This degrades the usefulness of your unit test suite.